# Group by clause, using field as sign +-

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the situation like below (simplified query):

```
select split_part(field1,'_',1) as order_sign
    , odp.dr_id
    , sum(odp.use_count) as usecount
    , cost
from table1
    inner join table2 odp on .. = odp.dr_id
    inner join .. = ..
    ...
where 
    condition1 AND condition2 AND ..
    AND (split_part(field1,'_',1) in ('in', 'out'))
group by split_part(field1,'_',1), odp.dr_id, cost
order by odp.dr_id
```

I have the result like:

```
"in"  ;8;1;70
"in"  ;24;2;70
"out" ;27;1;70
"in"  ;32;3;70
"in"  ;38;2;70
"out" ;44;1;70
"in"  ;52;3;70
"out" ;57;1;70
"in"  ;58;1;70
"in"  ;79;1;70
"out" ;79;2;70
"out" ;96;2;70
"out" ;114;1;70
"out" ;117;1;70
"out" ;124;2;70
"out" ;228;1;70
```

How could I use "in" as "minus sign", "out" as "plus sign", to get result like:

```
        8   ; -1 ;70)
        24  ; -2 ;70)
        27  ;  1 ;70)
        ...
        79  ;  (-1+2); 70
        ...
        228 ;  1; 70
```

Using postgresql? I want to get result using only SQL.

Comment: Like `CASE WHEN split_part(field1,'_',1) = 'in' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END *  sum(odp.use_count) AS usecount`? Your desired results don't match your sample data so I'm sort of guessing this is what you mean.

Comment: thanks, solved, just read a bit more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved, just thinking more)

```
with mycte as (
    select split_part(field1,'_',1) as order_sign
        , odp.dr_id
        , sum(odp.use_count) as usecount
        , cost
    from table1
        inner join table2 odp on .. = odp.dr_id
        inner join .. = ..
        ...
    where 
        condition1 AND condition2 AND ..
        AND (split_part(field1,'_',1) in ('in', 'out'))
    group by split_part(field1,'_',1), odp.dr_id, cost
    order by odp.dr_id
)
select dr_id,  
    sum(
        CASE 
            WHEN order_sign = 'in' then 0-usecount
            ELSE usecount
        END

    ) AS signed_usecount
    ,cost
from mycte
group by dr_id, cost
order by dr_id
```

Result as expected.